# Can I develop for both Android and iOS on a Windows 10 machine using QT Creator?

Tags: android, ios, qt

I need to develop an app for both Android and iOS. The project states to use QT Creator. Is this possible?

It appears that QT needs XCode to develop for iOS, however XCode is only available on Macs, and I have a Windows 10 machine. How would I do this using QT Creator? Do I need a virtual machine to run QT Creator on?

Or is there some other way to do this, even if we don't use QT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To develop apps for MacOS or iOS you need MacOS (it is not a Qt issue). That means you either use a Mac or use a virtual machine with MacOS.

Comment: So there is no other way to develop for iOS other than compiling on a Mac or an emulator of one?

Comment: That's correct. It's not like with Android to develop on any OS, sadly.

Comment: Where running macOS VMs is still only legal on macOS hosts, to my knowledge

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld there are some unofficial builds that work on Windows machine.